# Can we assign a group to a role in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are using AWS cloud and terraform with ansible  to deploy our current infrastructure.
The code is yml files where we can put whatever works m, but to my concern we cannot apply some group policies to a user role. is this possible or could it be that the console does not show the policies applied from a group to a role.

assigned in our usual modus operandi but i believe it does not work while the functionality may be provided by the usage of extra permissions like expressly specified iam/bucket access policies.

user-test: #this line declares role
assume_arn:
- arn:aws:iam::anonymised:user/test
- arn:aws:iam::anonymised:user/me
groups:
- tf-dev1-group
- tf-dev2-group
- tf-dev3-group
policies:
- athena-fulladmin-policy
- support_access

no error messages just lack of result

Comment: We can not attach IAM Groups to IAM roles. Groups are attached to IAM Users only.

Comment: you can define IAM managed policies which you can then assign to either IAM groups or IAM roles.